# Row wise logical operation on Data Table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have to perform row wise logical operation in data table, let me explain this with example. Suppose I have data table (DT) as given below

```
V1      V2        V3        V4      V5 
 AAE     CDG       2        0        0  
 AAE     CDG       2        5        5  
 AAE     ORY       2        4        4  
 AAE     ORY       2        0        0  
 AAE     ORY       2        5        5  
 AAE     ORY       2        3        3
```

Now, depending upon the value of V5, I want to add additional column V6 to data table, this is logical operation. I did something like this to do it-

```
DT[, V6 := if(V5 == 0){1
              }else if(V5 == 1){2
              }else if(V5 == 2){3
              }else if(V5 == 3){4
              }else if(V5 == 4){5
              }else if(V5 == 5){6}
    ]
```

But this does not give the desired result, which should be

```
V1   V2        V3      V4        V5   V6
 AAE CDG       2        0        0     1
 AAE CDG       2        5        5     6
 AAE ORY       2        4        4     5
 AAE ORY       2        0        0     1
 AAE ORY       2        5        5     6
 AAE ORY       2        3        3     4
```

Whereas gives the following result-

```
 V1   V2       V3       V4       V5    V6
 AAE CDG       2        0        0     1
 AAE CDG       2        5        5     1
 AAE ORY       2        4        4     1
 AAE ORY       2        0        0     1
 AAE ORY       2        5        5     1
 AAE ORY       2        3        3     1
```

This happens because first value of V5 (which is 0) is used in logical operation, instead of dynamically using one value or row value at a time. How can I change [,J] argument to get the desired results. I can use the for loop to do this, but it would be very in-efficient way of doing it.

Comment: +1. I've done this sort of thing, too (but with more complicated conditions). I think here, you can probably use `switch`. You can even write a function outside of the `DT[` call to test it out first, and then do `DT[,myfun(V5)]`. Oh, also, do what Geoffrey suggested: make a separate data.table with your mapping for each `unique(V5)`.

Comment: I solved this problem by calling the function in [,J] with argument of function as V5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
dat <- read.table(
text= "V1      V2        V3        V4      V5 
  AAE     CDG       2        0        0  
  AAE     CDG       2        5        5  
  AAE     ORY       2        4        4  
  AAE     ORY       2        0        0  
  AAE     ORY       2        5        5  
  AAE     ORY       2        3        3",header=TRUE)

dat$V6 <- ifelse(dat$V5 == 0,1,
                 ifelse(dat$V5 == 1,2,
                        ifelse(dat$V5 == 2,3,
                               ifelse(dat$V5 == 3,4,
                                      ifelse(dat$V5 == 4,5,
                                             ifelse(dat$V5 == 5,6,NA))))))
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, but better implementation is to use the function as J element with argument as V5

Comment: Upvoting useful comments and answers helps. Also, please post your solution so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just do

```
dat <- read.table(text= "V1      V2        V3        V4      V5 
+  AAE     CDG       2        0        0  
+  AAE     CDG       2        5        5  
+  AAE     ORY       2        4        4  
+  AAE     ORY       2        0        0  
+  AAE     ORY       2        5        5  
+  AAE     ORY       2        3        3  ",header=TRUE)
dat$V6 <- dat$V5 + 1
```

As @Steph said you can create a mapping table as follows and then merge the columns.

```
mapping <- data.frame(V5=c(0,1,2,3,4,5),V6=c(1,2,3,4,5,6))
merge(dat,mapping,by="V5")
```

Comment: Above is just an example of what value V6 can take, the actual function is much more complicated

Comment: @Pawan This assignment method is much cleaner than the one you were attempting to use and you can expand the complexity on the RHS if your example is dumbed down. Alternatively create a data.frame with the v5 value and the corresponding v6 value desired and perform a merge to get the v6 value.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers so far are in `data.frame` language. In `data.table` language you should use `DT[, V6 := ifelse...]` as opposed to `DT$V6 <- ifelse...` and you'd use the `[` instead of calling `merge`:

```
setkey(DT, V5)
DT[J(V5 = 0:5, V6 = 1:6), nomatch = 0]
```

But at least in the example in the OP it looks like the solution is simply:

```
DT[, V6 := V5 + 1]
```

Oh, and the reason your `if/else` doesn't work is because `if/else` doesn't operate on vectors and it simply takes the first value of your vector `V5`, which is indeed `0`, and returns `1`, which is effectively the same as writing `DT[, V6 := 1]`.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about `data.table` according to a test in this [tutorial](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.pdf), it is considerably faster than `data.frames` "...this was **1014 times** faster...".